# Custom property with setter

Tags: python, properties, descriptor

I am looking for a pure Python implementation of the `property` builtin to understand how  initialization works. I have found many that deal with the descriptor interface (`__get__`, `__set__`) but none describing the `setter` or `deleter` methods. Is this [definition](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Property_Definition) in the [Python Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) (roughly) the way it is implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property is a simple, straightforward descriptor. Descriptor protocol consists of three methods: `__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__`. Property for each of those operations simply calls user-provided functions.

```
class my_property(object):
    def __init__(self, getter, setter, deleter):
        self.getter  = getter
        self.setter  = setter
        self.deleter = deleter

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.getter(instance)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.setter(instance, value)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        self.deleter(instance)

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 42

    def get_x(self):
        print 'getter'
        return self._x

    def set_x(self, value):
        print 'setter'
        self._x = value

    def del_x(self):
        print 'deleter'
        del self._x

    x = my_property(get_x, set_x, del_x)

obj = Foo()
print obj.x
obj.x = 69
del obj.x
print obj.x
```

Comment: I am interested in how the setter method (property.setter) is implemented.

Comment: @Hernan: It changes `fset` and returns `self` (or possibly returns a copy of itself, I don't really remember). No rocket science involved.

Comment: That's what I thought, but in the link that I put in the post and by looking the operation of  a class in which I have subclassed from property and added a print(args, kwargs) in __init__ it seems that is creating the property again, not just change fset. Is this really the case? Why is that?

Comment: @Hernan: Well, returning a copy with changed `fset` is valid, too.

Answer (score -1):

As a comment: there is a simple way to add property to a Python list object. Warp in a class.

```
>>> class Foo(list): pass
>>> l = Foo([1,2,3])
>>> l.foo = 'bar'
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```